# not sure if this linux exercise is correct

Tags: linux, bash

Write a script which inputs a user’s name and state (location). If the user lives in
    either AZ or CA, they are charged a fee of $25. If the user lives in either OH, IN, or
    KY, they are charged no fee. Otherwise, they are charged a fee of $10. If their name is
    Zappa, Duke, or Keneally, their fee is doubled. Output their name and fee.

answer:

```
echo Hello, who am I talking to?
read varname
echo What state do you live in?
read varstate
FEE=0
case $varstate in
    AZ)
        FEE=25
        ;;
    CA)
        FEE=25
        break
        ;;
    OH)
        FEE=0
        break
        ;;
    IN)
        FEE=0
        break
        ;;
    KY)
        FEE=0
        break
        ;;
    *)
        FEE=10
        ;;
  esac
case $varname in
    Zappa)
        FEE += 25
        ;;
    Duke)
        FEE += 25
        break
        ;;
    Keneally)
        FEE += 25
        break
        ;;
    *)
        FEE += 10
        ;;
  esac
echo "Name: $varname - Fee: $FEE $"
```

Comment: So run it and test it.

Comment: Ask questions but don't ask the community to review your homework. Execute the application and test if the result is correct and/or write some test cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions say that the fees for Zappa, Duke, and Keneally are doubled, but you're adding 25. That will only be correct if they're also in AZ or CA. And you're adding 10 for everyone else, but that's not correct at all.

Use multiplication to double the fee.

You need to use an arithmetic statement `let expression` or `((expression))` to perform calculations in the shell.

Also, you can match multiple strings in the same case using `|`.

```
case $varname in
    Zappa|Duke|Keneally)
        ((FEE *= 2));;
esac
```